# pythonモジュールswemのimport方法

Tags: python, mecab

https://github.com/yagays/swem

↑このモジュールをimportしようとすると、以下画像のようなエラーになります。
こちらの解消方法を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
ImportError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1d3625db003a> in <module>
      1 from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
      2 
----> 3 from swem import MeCabTokenizer
      4 from swem import SWEM
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'MeCabTokenizer' from 'swem' (/Users/hoge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/swem/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく、参照先のリポジトリから直接インストールする必要があると思われます。

[2 code results in yagays/swem or view all results on GitHub](https://github.com/yagays/swem/search?q=MeCabTokenizer&unscoped_q=MeCabTokenizer)
[image: yagays]

---

pip install swem でインストールした場合は別のものが入るようです。

```
C:\Develop\Python>pip show swem
Name: swem
Version: 0.3.2
Summary: A portable document embedding using SWEM.
Home-page: https://github.com/yutayamazaki/swem
Author: Yuta Yamazaki
Author-email: yu.yamazakii@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\xusernamex\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: gensim, numpy
Required-by:
```

[We couldn’t find any code matching 'MeCabTokenizer' in yutayamazaki/swem](https://github.com/yutayamazaki/swem/search?q=MeCabTokenizer&unscoped_q=MeCabTokenizer)
[image: yutayamazaki]

Comment: 様   

ご返信ありがとうございます。gitからダウンロードして、対象のプロジェクトフォルダや、libフォルダに入れてモジュールを呼び出してみてはいますが、うまくいきません。  `ImportError: cannot import name 'MeCabTokenizer' from 'swem' (unknown location)` unknown locationとなっているのでパスなどを通す必要がある場合、手法を教えてください。

Comment: 上手くいかない原因は調べて見当が付きましたが、カスタマイズされた物のようなので、どうすればセットアップ出来るかまでは分かりません。作者は日本人のようなので、作者に問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます、そうしてみます！